# Windows updates breaking partition table

Tags: linux, windows, arch-linux, boot-partition

I have been using a dual boot setup for a while (Arch Linux + Windows 11). I recently had an issue with a Windows update, and a BOPS update at the same time.

This erased the partition table, thus making me boot directly into Windows, without grub, the BIOS was not showing my Linux partition in the boot section. Only the Windows one remained.

I am thus assuming it was because of the Windows update.

Comment: I doubt it erased the partition table.

Comment: That some Windows feature updates change the boot order to itself, for convenience (may require several reboots), is nothing new and it's just a matter of changing the boot order back to what it was at UEFI settings ("BIOS" actually died more than decade ago) > Boot menu. It DIDN'T erase the partition table (you wouldn't be booting anything, period). This and the subsequent answer is pure ignorance.

Comment: Only ways an update would try modify the partition table would be if: The WinRE partition is before the OS partition; The WinRE partition was too small a size to not allow for future `winre.wim` size increases; `bootrec` was used to correct a boot issue. Please clarify if motherboard is UEFI or BIOS _(these are **not** the same things)_ and please post the output of `lis par`: `diskpart` → `lis dis` → `sel dis <OS drive #>` → `lis par`. Windows doesn't recognize GRUB, so if an update tries to modify the partition table or WinRE's/WinPE's `bootrec` is used, it will almost always break GRUB.

Comment: No, it did not changed the boot order, there were a windows update, and at a reboot (needed for the update) the UEFI updated, leaving me with only the windows partition as bootable, even from the UEFI point of view.

In windows from the partition manager, the linux partition were not labeled anymore and it was written (0 partition) in any of the segments of the drive except for the windows ones. so please, instead of assuming I am straight up lying, consider reading and noticing that I wrote "ASSUMING" it was because of the windows update.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this problem, you'll have to boot through live image (Linux), mount your previous Linux partitions, save all your data and config files onto a USB drive, and proceed to reinstall Linux.

Comment: Why would a nuke-it approach be required?

Comment: I could not afford the time to look for a better way to do it, I am sure there are ways to do this in a better way, but it is working.

Comment: A nuke-it approach would never be recommended to resolve a boot issue, as it's wholly unnecessary. While a bad answer is still an answer, it would be more beneficial to you and the OP to offer a [better answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) than a nuke-it all approach, taking the time to research better options, then writing an answer on what approach you believe would be best _(is this the approach you would take on your own PC/laptop?)_

Comment: I am the op and this is the approach I took...